# Unable to print_r array

Tags: php, mysql

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
$p_id = project_id_from_project_name($page);
$project_tasks = tasks_list($p_id);
function PrintR($project_tasks) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($project_tasks);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

$page displays the correct thing and $p_id displays the id of the project, which is used in the function tasks_list shown below:

```
function tasks_list($p_id) {
    $project_tasks = array();
    $p_id = (int)$p_id;

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    $project_tasks = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `task_name` FROM `tasks` WHERE `project_id` = $p_id"));

    return $project_tasks;
}
```

The query is working and tested on my database however print_r displays no data?

Cannot see why?

Thanks

Comment: Where is `PrintR()` being called? Is your database connection open?

Comment: Try `print_r $project_tasks;` see what that gives. without the parentheses.

Comment: yes db connection is open, I realised I should be using print_r() but that displays this error:

( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Print_r() in C:\wamp\www\project\edit_task.php on line 12

Comment: Is your connection open ?

Comment: @Fred that displays a syntax error

Comment: where else does `project_id_from_project_name` come into play?

Comment: in several places, and it works successfully everywhere.

Comment: Nowhere in the code you've posted are you actually calling `print_r` (or `PrintR`).

Comment: Are you sure `task_list()` returns the correct information? Have you tried `var_dump($project_tasks);`?  

  
Just FYI.. instead of `echo '<pre>'; print_r($project_tasks); echo '</pre>';` you can also do: `echo '<pre>' . print_r($project_tasks, true) . '</pre>';` )

Comment: @user2286553 Can you specify or show us `C:\wamp\www\project\edit_task.php on line 12`

Comment: @TerrySeidler vardump displays this : array (size=1)
  'task_name' => string 'Task 1' (length=6)  - - - (Task 1 is the name of the first task)

Comment: @user2286553: Which means your array is fine! :-)  So, what's the problem here?

Comment: but it says array(size=1) when there are 10+ entries?

Comment: Shouldn't there be something inside your `array()`?

Comment: @user2286553: `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns one row at a time.  Check the docs: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: @user2286553: I guess so :-)  Are there any other issues you have?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I would like to display this array in a Select Input in PHP so you can select one from a drop down list?

Comment: @user2286553: Give it a try! :-)  If you still need help, ask a new question! :-D

Comment: @user2286553 perhaps perform some research first. Your taks can be done with a `foreach ($ArrayVar AS $ArrayValues) { echo $ArrayValues; }`  but you'd have to concat some HTML option attribs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you actually call PrintR() anywhere?

Note how the example below does not display anything:

```
<?php
    $data = array('hello', 'this', 'is', 'an', 'array');
    function PrintR($data) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($data, true) . '</pre>';
    }
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/L1wvfb

But this does:

```
<?php
    $data = array('hello', 'this', 'is', 'an', 'array');
    PrintR($data);


    function PrintR($data) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($data, true) . '</pre>';
    }
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/liJmZx

Note the added `PrintR($data);`. right at the start.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the PrintR() function, right after you are calling task_list(). But you are not actually calling PrintR(). The error you get 'Cannot redeclare print_r()' seems to indicate that you are trying to change the line from 'function PrintR($project_tasks) {' to 'function Print_r($project_tasks) {'...

```
$project_tasks = task_list($p_id);
PrintR($project_tasks);
function PrintR($project_tasks) { ... }
```

Comment: Is this an assumption? Because there is no evidence that the OP is doing something like this

Comment: Yes this is an assumption, based on the error he was getting 'Cannot redeclare Print_r()'. Which would happen if the code was declaring a line like 'function print_r($project_tasks) {' since print_r already exists. Hence the 'seems to indicate' part.. I am assuming they are seeing the function declaration as a call, rather than just a declaration. (error taken from comments section of question)

Comment: Please make sure you include that you are making a logical assumption based on the details provided; it'll help clear  things up in the future

Comment: My apologies, I am new to the site.

Comment: Which is why I decided to make a comment rather downvote your answer :)